# Toshiba Satellite L300D, remove BIOS password

Tags: bios, password-recovery, cmos

I have this Toshiba Satellite L300D laptop with unknown BIOS password. As I turn laptop on, message appears "enter current password". When I get it wrong three times, laptop turns off. I tried to short-circuit CMOS battery, which seemed to be a success, because now I get this message "The firmware has detected that a CMOS battery failure occured. [F1] Continue, [F2] Open setup". As I understand, this message means CMOS memory has failed and basically BIOS settings were removed (password including). Unfortunately pressing F1/F2 gets me back to a window of "enter current password". How on Earth do I wipe CMOS data and reset BIOS password on this laptop, any suggestions?

Comment: It’s actually more common, for it NOT to be possible to reset a BIOS password, otherwise it as a security feature would typically be useless

Comment: Did you try [this method](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C9zrcx0PDhg)?

Answer (score 1):

You have to know the BIOS password to remove it properly.

To "wipe out the password" means having Toshiba replace the BIOS Chip.

Manufacturers have made their BIOS passwords very secure and you need to keep records.